# How to refactor two functions that require all of the same but one parameter?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have two methods that take all but one of the same parameters and run the same code except one additional line for one of the methods. I'm trying to decide what the best approach is to clean up the functions so I'm not duplicating code. Here are the methods in question.

I've tried using a `try/except` clause, but I feel like that is clunky and overkill. I am considering adding a param to a function that notes if the intent is to create or edit a file but that feels too restrictive.

```
def create_file(self, file_blob, filename, commit_message, committer_info, branch):
    json_file_data = self._file_data(file_blob, commit_message, committer_info, branch)
    content_url = '{}/{}'.format(self._github_content_url, filename)
    response = self._request(content_url, method='PUT', data=json_file_data)
    self._handle_errors(response)
```

```
def edit_file(self, file_blob, filename, commit_message, committer_info, branch):
    file_blob_sha = self._latest_blob_sha_for_file(branch, filename)
    content_url = '{}/{}'.format(self._github_content_url, filename)
    json_file_data = self._file_data(file_blob, commit_message, committer_info, branch, file_blob_sha)
    response = self._request(content_url, method='PUT', data=json_file_data)
    self._handle_errors(response)
```

Comment: Put the common code in a separate function and call it from each of the two shown in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reusability calls sometimes for using functions, hence you could have like a private function that handles the common part of both the `edit_file` and `create_file` as such:

```
def _process_file(json_file_data, filename):
    content_url = '{}/{}'.format(self._github_content_url, filename)
    response = self._request(content_url, method='PUT', data=json_file_data)
    self._handle_errors(response)

def create_file(self, file_blob, filename, commit_message, committer_info, branch):
    json_file_data = self._file_data(file_blob, commit_message, committer_info, branch)
    _process_file(json_file_data, filename)

def edit_file(self, file_blob, filename, commit_message, committer_info, branch):
    file_blob_sha = self._latest_blob_sha_for_file(branch, filename)
    json_file_data = self._file_data(file_blob, commit_message, committer_info, branch, file_blob_sha)
    _process_file(json_file_data, filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between `create_file` and `edit_file` is the function you call in order to produce a value for `file_blob_sha`. You can pretend that  `create_file` called a function that returned `None` (or whatever the default value for that parameter to `_file_data` is).

Define a common base function that takes the necessary function as an argument, rather than hard-coding it into the body of `create_file` or `edit_file`.

```
def _base(self,
          file_blob,
          filename,
          commit_message,
          committer_info,
          branch,
          fn):
    file_blob_sha = fn(branch, filename)

    json_file_data = self._file_data(file_blob, commit_message, committer_info, branch, file_blob_sha)
    content_url = '{}/{}'.format(self._github_content_url, filename)
    response = self._request(content_url, method='PUT', data=json_file_data)
    self._handle_errors(response)
```

(Note the body looks exactly like `edit_file`; you've just replaced the hard-coded reference to `self._latest_blob_sha_for_file` with a function argument.)

Each of your other functions then simply calls `_base` with an appropriate function argument. In the case of `create_file`, that's an explicit function that ignores its arguments and returns `None`.

```
def create_file(self, file_blob, filename, commit_message, committer_info, branch):
    return self._base(
        file_blob,
        filename,
        commit_message,
        committer_info,
        branch,
        lambda *args: None)

def edit_file(self, file_blob, filename, commit_message, committer_info, branch):
    return self._base(
        file_blob,
        filename,
        commit_message,
        committer_info, 
        branch,
        self._latest_blob_sha_for_file)
```

---

You can reduce the boilerplate further by defining a function that *returns* an appropriate method by closing over the function argument. In this approach, you don't have access to `self` yet to create a bound method to use in `edit_file`, so you have to pass `self` explicitly to the callback function.

```
class SomeClass:
    def _make_method(fn):
        def _base(self, file_blob, filename, commit_message, committer_info, branch):
            file_blob_sha = fn(self, branch, filename)

            json_file_data = self._file_data(file_blob, commit_message, committer_info, branch, file_blob_sha)
            content_url = '{}/{}'.format(self._github_content_url, filename)
            response = self._request(content_url, method='PUT', data=json_file_data)
            self._handle_errors(response)
        return _base

    def _latest_blob_sha_for_file(self, branch, filename):
        ...

    create_file = _make_method(lambda *args: None)
    edit_file = _make_method(_latest_blob_sha_for_file)

    del _make_method
```

Note that `_make_method` isn't intended to be a method itself; it's just a helper function used to define `create_file` and `edit_file` so we remove it from the class namespace before the class is constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add a new parameter:

```
def manipulate_file(self, file_blob, filename, commit_message, committer_info, branch, edit = False):
    args = [file_blob, filename, commit_message, committer_info, branch]
    if edit:
        file_blob_sha = self._latest_blob_sha_for_file(branch, filename)
        args += [file_blob_sha]
    content_url = '{}/{}'.format(self._github_content_url, filename)
    json_file_data = self._file_data(*args)
    response = self._request(content_url, method='PUT', data=json_file_data)
    self._handle_errors(response)
```